# ParseError and incorrect coordinates

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm having trouble with the game I'm creating in Turtle. Whenever I try and run the program I get a traceback error: `ParseError: bad input on line 69 in main.py`. But earlier (when the error didn't occur) my coordinates didn't work properly. I think I typed in the right ones, but it doesn't work. In the game you need to hit the fruit. So mainly the game goes like this: if you miss the fruit it should take one point from your score and one heart from your lives. At first it checks if you don't have a score of 0. If you hit the fruit you should get +1 point. But sadly, if I shoot anywhere in the left side of the window I get a +1 score. No matter the distance.

The code in which I suspect the problem is:

```
def cannon_shooting():
  bullet1 = random.randint(1, 4)
  global live_score
  if live_score >= 100:
    bullet1 = 5
  if bullet1 == 1:
    bullet.color('black')
  if bullet1 == 2:
    bullet.color('green')
  if bullet1 == 3:
    bullet.color('red')
  if bullet1 == 4:
    bullet.color('grey')
  if bullet1 == 5:
    bullet.color('white')
  bullet.goto(cannon_x, -30)
  bullet.showturtle()
  bullet.goto(cannon_x, 130)
  if bullet.ycor() == enemy.ycor() - 10:
    if not bullet.xcor() == enemy.xcor() - 10:
      if live_score == 0:
        if live_score == 100:
          score.color('white')
        live_score = 0
        score.clear()
        if live_score >= 0:
          score.write("Your score: %s" % live_score, font=(None, 11, "bold"))
      else:
        if live_score == 100:
          score.color('white')
        live_score = live_score - 1
        score.clear()
        if live_score >= 0:
          score.write("Your score: %s" % live_score, font=(None, 11, "bold"))
      move_speed = random.randint(1, 10)
      lives = lives - 1
    if bullet.xcor() = enemy.xcor() - 10:
      if live_score == 100:
        score.color('white')
      live_score = live_score + 1
      score.clear()
      if live_score >= 0:
        score.write("Your score: %s" % live_score, font=(None, 11, "bold"))
      enemy1 = random.randint(1, 3)
      move_speed = random.randint(1, 10)
  if live_score == 100:
    score.clear()
    cannon.goto(0, -100)
    cannon.hideturtle()
    enemy.hideturtle()
    bullet.hideturtle()
    bullet.goto(0, -30)
    win.color('green')
    win.write("Congratulations!", font=(None, 20, "bold"))
    win.goto(-140, -40)
    win.write("You scored 100 points!", font=(None, 20, "bold"))
  if lives == 0:
    score.clear()
    cannon.goto(0, -100)
    cannon.hideturtle()
    enemy.hideturtle()
    bullet.hideturtle()
    bullet.goto(0, -30)
    game_over.color('red')
    game_over.write("Game Over", font=(None, 20, "bold"))
    game_over.goto(-140, -40)
    game_over.write("You scored %d points!" % live_score, font=(None, 20, "bold"))
  bullet.hideturtle()
```

Whole code:

```
import random
import turtle

#images
image_coconut = "Coconut.png"
image_banana = "Banana.png"
image_pineapple = "Pineapple.png"
image_cannon = "Cannon.png"

#definitions
live_score = 0
screen = turtle.Screen()
wn = turtle.Screen()
cannon = turtle.Turtle()
enemy = turtle.Turtle()
score = turtle.Turtle()
score1 = turtle.Turtle()
background = turtle.Turtle()
reset = turtle.Turtle()
bullet = turtle.Turtle()
overlay = turtle.Turtle()
enemy_x = enemy.xcor()
enemy_y = enemy.ycor()
win = turtle.Turtle()
game_over = turtle.Turtle()
lives = 3
cannon_x = 0
cannon_x
move_speed = 2
enemy1 = 0
score_goto = 0

def cannon_shooting():
  bullet1 = random.randint(1, 4)
  global live_score
  if live_score >= 100:
    bullet1 = 5
  if bullet1 == 1:
    bullet.color('black')
  if bullet1 == 2:
    bullet.color('green')
  if bullet1 == 3:
    bullet.color('red')
  if bullet1 == 4:
    bullet.color('grey')
  if bullet1 == 5:
    bullet.color('white')
  bullet.goto(cannon_x, -30)
  bullet.showturtle()
  bullet.goto(cannon_x, 130)
  if bullet.ycor() == enemy.ycor() - 10:
    if not bullet.xcor() == enemy.xcor() - 10:
      if live_score == 0:
        if live_score == 100:
          score.color('white')
        live_score = 0
        score.clear()
        if live_score >= 0:
          score.write("Your score: %s" % live_score, font=(None, 11, "bold"))
      else:
        if live_score == 100:
          score.color('white')
        live_score = live_score - 1
        score.clear()
        if live_score >= 0:
          score.write("Your score: %s" % live_score, font=(None, 11, "bold"))
      move_speed = random.randint(1, 10)
      lives = lives - 1
    if bullet.xcor() = enemy.xcor() - 10:
      if live_score == 100:
        score.color('white')
      live_score = live_score + 1
      score.clear()
      if live_score >= 0:
        score.write("Your score: %s" % live_score, font=(None, 11, "bold"))
      enemy1 = random.randint(1, 3)
      move_speed = random.randint(1, 10)
  if live_score == 100:
    score.clear()
    cannon.goto(0, -100)
    cannon.hideturtle()
    enemy.hideturtle()
    bullet.hideturtle()
    bullet.goto(0, -30)
    win.color('green')
    win.write("Congratulations!", font=(None, 20, "bold"))
    win.goto(-140, -40)
    win.write("You scored 100 points!", font=(None, 20, "bold"))
  if lives == 0:
    score.clear()
    cannon.goto(0, -100)
    cannon.hideturtle()
    enemy.hideturtle()
    bullet.hideturtle()
    bullet.goto(0, -30)
    game_over.color('red')
    game_over.write("Game Over", font=(None, 20, "bold"))
    game_over.goto(-140, -40)
    game_over.write("You scored %d points!" % live_score, font=(None, 20, "bold"))
  bullet.hideturtle()


#image adding
screen.addshape(image_coconut)
screen.addshape(image_banana)
screen.addshape(image_pineapple)
screen.addshape(image_cannon)

def cannon_left():
  global cannon_x
  if cannon_x == -140:
    cannon_x = 140
    cannon.goto(cannon_x, -100)
  cannon_x = cannon_x - 10
  cannon.goto(cannon_x, -100)
  bullet.goto(cannon_x, -30)

def cannon_right():
  global cannon_x
  if cannon_x == 140:
    cannon_x = -140
    cannon.goto(cannon_x, -100)
  cannon_x = cannon_x + 10
  cannon.goto(cannon_x, -100)
  bullet.goto(cannon_x, -30)

#setup
screen.bgcolor('white')

game_over.hideturtle()
game_over.speed(0)
game_over.penup()
game_over.goto(-100, 0)

win.hideturtle()
win.speed(0)
win.penup()
win.goto(-100, 0)

bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.speed(5)
bullet.penup()
bullet.shape('circle')
bullet.goto(0, -140)
bullet.left(90)

enemy.speed(0)
enemy.penup()
enemy.hideturtle()
enemy.goto(0, 140)
screen.addshape(image_coconut)
enemy.shape(image_coconut)
enemy.showturtle()

cannon.speed(0)
cannon.penup()
cannon.hideturtle()
cannon.goto(0, -100)
screen.addshape(image_cannon)
cannon.shape(image_cannon)
cannon.showturtle()
cannon.left(90)

score.speed(0)
score.penup()
score.hideturtle()
score.goto(-45, -190)
score.color('black')
score.write("Your score: %s" % live_score, font=(None, 11, "bold"))

#bindings
wn.onkey(cannon_right, "D")
wn.onkey(cannon_left, "A")
wn.onkey(cannon_right, "Right")
wn.onkey(cannon_left, "Left")
wn.onkey(cannon_shooting, "SPACE")

#movement
enemy.forward(move_speed)
if enemy.xcor() == 140:
  enemy.left(180)
  enemy.forward(move_speed)
if enemy.xcor() == -140:
  enemy.right(180)
  enemy.forward(move_speed)
  if enemy1 == 1:
    screen.addshape(image_banana)
    enemy.shape(image_banana)
  if enemy1 == 2:
    screen.addshape(image_pineapple)
    enemy.shape(image_pineapple)
  if enemy1 == 3:
    enemy.shape(image_coconut)

#others
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Note: I'm creating the game in `Trinket.io`. To see the program in `Trinket`, click [here](https://trinket.io/python/ed2c612824).

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._ I'm pretty sure this block of code if far from being a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you say `if bullet.xcor() = enemy.xcor() - 10:`.  `=` is for assignment, but you can't make an assignment in an `if` block.  You should change it to `if bullet.xcor() == enemy.xcor() - 10:`

Comment: That doesn't help me. Yes, it fixes the error, but the coordinates are still messed up.